# JQuery $.ajax request not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, http-headers

I'm using a jquery to make an $.ajax request. It works fine in chrome/firefox and other browsers as far as I know however in IE it works first time then when a second request is made in IE the ajax fails with a 406 non acceptable error.

I've tried setting different accept headers with no luck. Any ideas?

```
$.ajax({

    type: Request.method,

    url: Request.request_url,

    cache: false,

    data: Request.getVarsString(),

    dataType: "text",

    beforeSend: function(req){
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml/application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"); 
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-gb,en;q=0.5"); 
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        Request.loadBeforeSend(id);
    },

    success: function(replyData){
        Request.requestComplete(id, replyData);
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        alert(textStatus+" "+jqXHR.status);
        //Request.requestComplete(id, replyData);
    }

});
```

Im using a get method.
Request is a static class with some methods and variables that i use to make an Ajax request

Comment: What is the `Request` global that you are using?

Comment: Its a static class I made. Im not great at the terminology

Comment: which version of IE? are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Have you created an instance of the "class"? It looks like you're trying to directly access the class's methods. For example: `var request = new Request();` or `var request = Object.create(Request);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure why IE was doing it but I have a hashed URL. At the time it was displaying a hash of "#!/querystring" but when I changed it to "#!querystring" it worked fine.
I'd be interesting in knowing if anyone knows why IE doesn't like the first example.

Comment: Do you understand what a hash is and how it responds to URIs? It's a bookmark to a specific `a name=""` in your HTML and will not make a server request unless you specify the entire URI or URL path.

Comment: Yeah I understand. You realise they can be caught in JS which can in turn make a server request?

Answer (score 0):

The older version of IE don't accept request type like PUT, DELETE, they accept only POST and GET. Maybe your method is not accepted ny IE?

Comment: jQuery will emulate the PUT or DELETE request that's not supported by the given browser. The question should be whether or not the back end is setup to receive more than just $_POST and $_GET.